# Spring Security Jax-rs OAuth2 with JWT example

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a Jax-RS application that uses spring for the component wiring and spring security for the authentication and authorization part.
I have been trying to configure spring security with OAuth2 and JWT tokens but there is not any good sample to follow.
The only one that I was able to find is this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth
but it doesn't really shed any light on how the authentication part is done, for example how to obtain a token or how to send it (cookies or header)
Is anyone aware of any good example on this specific setup?

Best.

Comment: You have progressed ?

Comment: @StephaneEybert yes, I was able to make this working, I have already answered my own question ;) please checkout the https://gist.github.com/maxsap/da154f99a2dbb414471a for more info, I think all the configuration classes required are in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any good examples other that the ones mentioned in the original post.
I have successfully managed to get this working.
For anyone interested I have created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/maxsap/da154f99a2dbb414471a).
I would like to create a full project when I find some spare time